# Multiplication using string operator

Tags: ios, swift, string, multiplication

Hi I would like to multiply 5 * 5 but instead of writing the "*" symbol I would like to store it in a var but I just cant figure out how to do it

What I don't want to  do:

```
var sum = 5 * 5
print(sum)
```

What I want to do:

```
var a = "*"
var sum = 5 a 5
print(sum)
```

Comment: Please help its for a project

Comment: why are you store it in var? is it change ? (ex: * / + -) or it get from user input?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your requirement after writing simple function to that process ,

```
var a = "*" //your changing operator 

func calc(type:String,val1:Int,val2:Int)->Int{

    //you can change values types to double if you want

    switch type {
    case "*": return val1*val2
    case "/": return val1/val2
    case "-": return val1-val2
    case "+": return val1+val2
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

print(calc(type: a, val1: 5, val2: 5))// result 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let multiply: (Int, Int) -> Int = (*)
let product = multiply(5, 5)
```

```swift
var operate: (Int, Int) -> Int

operate = (*)
let product = operate(5, 5)

operate = (+)
let sum = operate(5, 5)
```